# setting type TIMESTAMPWITH TIME ZONE to JDBC callable statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I search records in my oracle db 11g using search procedure. I'd like to search by
column whose type is TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

How could I set my Calendar object to JDBC Callable statement? When I used standard oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ class, mapped Calendar to it and tried to set it to JDBC, JDBC threw SQL exception - Illegal Conversion

thx:)

Answer (score 1):

use [TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm)

Read [this](http://puretech.paawak.com/2010/11/02/how-to-handle-oracle-timestamp-with-timezone-from-java/) also.